# Segmentation Fault after float division in 64bit NASM

Tags: assembly, floating-point, nasm, x86-64, simd

I am having trouble trying to get a simple miles per gallon program working that inputs floats, divides them, and prints the result. I have not yet used floats in NASM, so I'm not sure if it isn't reading the numbers right or just not dividing them right. I get a segmentation fault as soon as the program divides the two numbers. Any thoughts?

```
extern printf, scanf, puts
SECTION .text
global main
main:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp ; for correct debugging

    xor eax, eax

    ;welcome message
    mov rdi, welcome
    call puts

    ;prompt
    mov rdi, miles_prompt
    call puts

    ;input
    mov rdi, fmt
    movq xmm0, [miles]
    mov al, 1 ;1 float argument
    mov rax, 1 ;no other arguments...is this right?
    call scanf

    ;prompt
    mov rdi, gallons_prompt
    call puts

    ;input
    mov rdi, fmt
    movq xmm0, [gallons]
    mov al, 1
    mov rax, 1
    call scanf

    ;divide floats
    movq xmm0, [miles]
    movq xmm1, [gallons]
    divsd xmm0, xmm1

    ;print answer
    mov rdi, answer
    mov rsi, rax
    mov rax, 1
    call printf

    ;exit(0)
    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp
    ret


SECTION .data
    welcome: db "*** MPG Calc ***", 10, 0
    miles_prompt: db "How many miles did you travel: ", 0
    gallons_prompt: db "How many gallons of gas did you use: ", 0
    answer: db "MPG: %lf", 0
    fmt: db "%lf", 0
    miles: dq 0, 0
    gallons: dq 0, 0
```

Here is my Terminal:

```
$ nasm -f elf64 -s mpg.asm
$ g++ mpg.o -o ./mpg
$ ./mpg
*** MPG Calc ***

How many miles did you travel: 
6
How many gallons of gas did you use: 
4
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Have you stepped through with a debugger (like GDB) to see what is in the registers by the time it does the division?

Comment: I'm working on that right now. Something is wrong with the scanf(), so I'm trying different things with that.

Comment: Whenever you call a _C_ function that takes variable number of arguments (like scanf and printf) you need to set the number of vector registers used in _RAX_. It appears you did this for scanf but not for printf. Since your printf is being passed 1 vector register (with the float to print), _RAX_ should be one.

Comment: The `syscall` at the end needs to be removed. If you make the change I  mentioned above with pushing _RBP_ at the start you would end with `mov rsp, rbp` `pop rbp` . The `ret` should then be enough to return to the _C_ runtime where it will properly exit for you.

Comment: As for your `scanf` you need to pass it an address where the floating point number will be stored.

Comment: Also think you want to use a format specifier of `%lf` for doubles if that was your intention instead of `%a`

Comment: I should point something out. You need to align the stack to a 16-byte boundary before any _C_ library calls (most especially if you are using floating point). When a _C_ function is called like `main` the stack is misaligned by 8. You need to subtract 8 from RSP to realign it OR push a value on the stack. Your prologue code would have done this but you did `mov rbp, rsp` but you really need `push rbp` `mov rbp, rsp` . This would have saved RBP and aligned the stack to 16-bytes

Comment: The reason I commented about doubles is because you used `divsd` which divides double floats, not floats.

Comment: I've edited my code. I don't get a segmentation fault but the result shows up as -nan. Any ideas on that?

Comment: If you are suppose to be using 32-bit floats then the [code at this link](http://www.capp-sysware.com/misc/stackoverflow/40953674/mpg.asm) should work. I quickly hacked up some changes based on the previous comments. I didn't modify your code for efficiency.

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate the comments too.